# How to get the full type name?

Tags: c#, .net

have a class, can I get the full type name in the form like A,B?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) on the Type instance:

```
typeof(string).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Or:

```
typeof(YourClass).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Also, if you have an instance of an object, and want to know the full type name from that; use `GetType()` to get the Type instance from the instance.

Comment: this will print something like: `"System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Type.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  in case you're not interested in the assembly properties

Following your example:

```
typeof(A).FullName;
```

or from an instance of A:

```
anA.GetType().FullName;
```

Comment: this will print something like: `"System.String"`